# How to create a List in Java

Tags: java

I tried to use `List` in Java but it says "symbol not found".

I tried the following code:

```
List<int> myList=new List<int>();
myList=new JList<int>();
```

which is not at all working.

Comment: You cannot parameterise generics with primitive types in Java.

Comment: Also you can't instantiate an interface in Java either...

Comment: You need this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Comment: Also, `JList` is a very different thing from `List`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three immediate issues here:

1. Type parameters cannot be primitive; you need to use the appropriate [wrapper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class). In your case, it would be `List<Integer>`.
2. [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface: you cannot instantiate it. You need to instantiate a class that implements it, a common option is [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

   ```
   List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ```

   In Java 7 and above you don't actually have to restate the type parameter on the right hand side of the assignment:

   ```
   List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
3. `List` / `ArrayList` are not in the `java.lang` package, so you have to import them by including the appropriate `import` statements at the top of your file (under the package declaration, if there is any):

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   ```

   That's why it's complaining that the "symbol cannot be found".

Comment: Plus you need to import List and Arraylist.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I just saw that this was another issue for the OP, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Im just very new to learning Java. Thats why I code like it is c sharp. Another thing. What does interface mean in java? What is the meaning of interface when you use c sharp?

Comment: @user1625766 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 0):

The two problems with your following List declaration

```
List<int> myList=new List<int>();
```

are:

1. List works on objects so you need to use Integer, instead of primitive int
2. List is an interface so cannot instantiate it, use ArrayList an implementation class of List interface to create an instance.

You need to define your List as:

```
    List<Integer> myList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Also make sure that you import the follwing classes in your code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `int` cannot be used in paramertized types. You can use `Integer` instead.

Secondly, `List` is an interface, you cannot instantiate a `List`. You can use the `ArrayList` class which implements `List`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Or:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```